# Calculate decile limits in Stata

Tags: statistics, limit, stata

Here is my problem: I have monthly income data and have used the "xtile" command to calculate the 5% quantiles

```
xtile income_decile=bbh5101, nq(20)
```

How can I find out which borders Stata used to allocate the observation to a certain quantile bin, e.g. first quantile bin from 0 to 800€, second quantile bin from 801 to 1600€ and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just want the percentiles. Use the corresponding `_pctile` command. For example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

xtile q = weight, nq(10)

_pctile weight, nq(10)

sort weight
list weight q

return list
```

Checking those two lists, should be useful. See also the *Methods and formulas*  section in **[D] pctile**.

The result:

```
. list weight q

     +-------------+
     | weight    q |
     |-------------|
  1. |  1,760    1 |
  2. |  1,800    1 |
  3. |  1,800    1 |
  4. |  1,830    1 |
  5. |  1,930    1 |
     |-------------|
  6. |  1,980    1 |
  7. |  1,990    1 |
  8. |  2,020    1 |
  9. |  2,040    2 |
 10. |  2,050    2 |
     |-------------|
 11. |  2,070    2 |
 12. |  2,110    2 |
 13. |  2,120    2 |
 14. |  2,130    2 |
 15. |  2,160    2 |
     |-------------|
 16. |  2,200    3 |
 17. |  2,200    3 |
 18. |  2,230    3 |
 19. |  2,240    3 |
 20. |  2,280    3 |
     |-------------|
 21. |  2,370    3 |
 22. |  2,410    3 |
 23. |  2,520    3 |
 24. |  2,580    4 |
 25. |  2,640    4 |
     |-------------|
 26. |  2,650    4 |
 27. |  2,650    4 |
 28. |  2,670    4 |
 29. |  2,690    4 |
 30. |  2,730    4 |
     |-------------|
 31. |  2,750    5 |
 32. |  2,750    5 |
 33. |  2,830    5 |
 34. |  2,830    5 |
 35. |  2,930    5 |
     |-------------|
 36. |  3,170    5 |
 37. |  3,180    5 |
 38. |  3,200    6 |
 39. |  3,210    6 |
 40. |  3,220    6 |
     |-------------|
 41. |  3,250    6 |
 42. |  3,260    6 |
 43. |  3,280    6 |
 44. |  3,300    6 |
 45. |  3,310    6 |
     |-------------|
 46. |  3,330    7 |
 47. |  3,350    7 |
 48. |  3,370    7 |
 49. |  3,370    7 |
 50. |  3,400    7 |
     |-------------|
 51. |  3,420    7 |
 52. |  3,420    7 |
 53. |  3,430    8 |
 54. |  3,470    8 |
 55. |  3,600    8 |
     |-------------|
 56. |  3,600    8 |
 57. |  3,670    8 |
 58. |  3,690    8 |
 59. |  3,690    8 |
 60. |  3,700    8 |
     |-------------|
 61. |  3,720    9 |
 62. |  3,740    9 |
 63. |  3,830    9 |
 64. |  3,880    9 |
 65. |  3,900    9 |
     |-------------|
 66. |  4,030    9 |
 67. |  4,060    9 |
 68. |  4,060    9 |
 69. |  4,080   10 |
 70. |  4,130   10 |
     |-------------|
 71. |  4,290   10 |
 72. |  4,330   10 |
 73. |  4,720   10 |
 74. |  4,840   10 |
     +-------------+

. 
. return list

scalars:
                 r(r1) =  2020
                 r(r2) =  2160
                 r(r3) =  2520
                 r(r4) =  2730
                 r(r5) =  3190
                 r(r6) =  3310
                 r(r7) =  3420
                 r(r8) =  3700
                 r(r9) =  4060
```

You can put the percentiles in a variable. Just use:

`pctile p = weight, nq(10)`

Comment: ATTENTION: While this works with income data the resulting quantiles aren't correct. That is due to the fact that xtile does not create groups of equal size. Use range to calculate an index variable and then apply xtile on that.